# dividir en dos listas

Tags: python, lista

Como se puede modificar una lista para obtener dos listas

```
lista= ['100,5','13,2','30,34','12,3']
```

tengo esta lista pero necesito obtener esto:

```
lista_1= ['100','13','30','12']

lista_2= ['5','2','34','3']
```

Comment: que as intentando hasta ahora? puedes colocar el codigo

Comment: `lista_2 = [x.split(",")[1] for x in lista_1]`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
lista = ['100,5','13,2','30,34','12,3']

tupla1, tupla2 = list(zip(*[n.split(',') for n in lista]))

print(tupla1)
print(tupla2)

('100', '13', '30', '12')
('5', '2', '34', '3')
```

La "magia" la hace esta construcción: `tupla1, tupla2 = list(zip(*[n.split(',') for n in lista]))`, que básicamente:

- `[n.split(',') for n in lista]` divide cada cadena de `lista` en una tupla de dos elementos a partir de la coma como separador, el resultado final será una lista con tuplas.
- Con `list(zip(*[...]))` combinamos los primeros elementos de cada tupla en una tupla y los segundos en otra.
- Finalmente se `desempaqueta` las dos tuplas en dos variables, a los efectos prácticos la dos tuplas funcionan cómo listas, pero si aun así necesitaras listas reales, simplemente conviértelas mediante `list(tupla1)` o `list(tupla2)`